# what is the difference between SMPP and SMS

Tags: sms, integration, smpp

Please I'll like to know the difference between SMS and SMPP or at the very least get pointed to a good resource that breaks down this difference in layman terms. I'm currently on a project where the product vendor says the product only supports SMPP for inbound messages so it cannot be integrated to an SMS gateway. I've tried researching the fundamental peculiarities of SMPP that makes the integration with an SMS gateway for inbound messages impossible for this product but my research has yielded nothing material so far.

I'll really appreciate your feedback as the project is basically at an impasse due to the insistence of the vendor on SMPP.

Answer (score 2):

SMPP is the protocol used to send SMS. Currently there are 2 ways to send a SMS. Either by SMPP (beneath the TCP protocol) or by SS7 (which requires hardware and is costly).
Usually SMS gateways are SMPP which is weird that you are not able to integrate it with it.

In brief, the SMPP protocol does the below:

- Client binds to the server (Bind Request) / Server Accept or Reject
  bind (Bind Response)
- Client Sends SMS (Submit-SM) / Server accepts or Rejects SMS (Submit
  Resp) server also includes the message Id
- Server sends the DLR with the same message Id in the submit
  response(Deliver-SM) / Client acknowledge the DLR (Deliver Resp)

Theres also an Enquire Link sent from the client and its response from the server to keep the connection from timing out usually 30 seconds.

Here's a link describing the SMPP Protocol in details:
http://opensmpp.org/specs/smppv34_gsmumts_ig_v10.pdf